# Document comparison / similarity using Whoosh Python Search Library

Tags: python, search, whoosh

How do I get a similarity measure of a document using Whoosh?

I want to create a "Related" feature that ranks other previously indexed documents that have a high similarity to a document.

Do I input the document as a long query string? Do I add the document to the index and extract a similarity query result somehow from there?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Whoosh searcher class has a method called ['more_like()'](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/api/searching.html?highlight=rank#whoosh.searching.Searcher.more_like).

It allows you to compare and indexed document to other indexed documents and returns a list of documents similar to the given document.

And the [class whoosh.searching.Hit](http://packages.python.org/Whoosh/api/searching.html?highlight=rank#whoosh.searching.Hit) can give a rank and a score.

Updated links:

`more_like()` : https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/searching.html#whoosh.searching.Searcher.more_like
`whoosh.searching.Hit` : https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/searching.html#whoosh.searching.Hit